# CNN Keras Multi Label Output Prediction

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to implement the CNN code from Andreas Werdich: https://github.com/awerdich/physionet

" The goal of this project was to implement a deep-learning algorithm that classifies electrocardiogram (ECG) recordings from a single-channel handheld ECG device into four distinct categories: normal sinus rhythm (N), atrial fibrillation (A), other rhythm (O), or too noisy to be classified (~). "

Executing the code works fine. But now after the model was trained I'm not sure how to predict a different ECG signal. He uses ECG signal stored in hdf5 files.

"For each group of data in the hdf5 file representing a single ECG time series, the following metadata was saved as attribute:

- baseline voltage in uV
- bit depth
- gain
- sampling frequency
- measurement units"

After training I saved the model with

model.save(filepath)
I put it on filedropper: http://www.filedropper.com/ecgcnn

And I have an hdf5 file full with ECG signals that I'd like to predict: http://www.filedropper.com/physioval

I tried using the model.predict function, but it didn't work. I'm not quite sure how to pass on the ECG signal, because I need 4 different classifications.

Does anyone know how I can make the prediction work?

Thanks

Comment: Give more info about "it didn't work". If it's the error then put the traceback here too.

Comment: If the result isn't good but it runs, that's probably about the data pre-processing, put the predicting code here.

Comment: I can't even find a `model.predict` in the repo you provide.

Comment: BTW don't forget to commend here if you edited your post, it won't notify otherwise.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.
I figured it out. Sorry for the bad formulation.